# select con eloquent y laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

espero puedan ayudarme con este problema.
Tengo una tabla servicios con los campos descripción, costo, duración, tengo un select que lleno con la descripción de cada servicio mediante un foreach

[image: select y un input]

necesito que el input se llene con el costo de la seleccion que haga, pero solo se llena con el ultimo costo del foreach, este es el codigo

```
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tratamiento</label>
                            <select class="form-control">
                                @foreach ($servicios as $servicio)
                                    <option value="">{{$servicio->servicio}}</option>

                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputCosto">Costo</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">S/</span>
                                <input type="number" value="{{$servicio->costo}}" class="form-control" id="inputCosto">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias ante todo, la pregunta es
Como hacer para que el input costo se llene con el costo del servicio que elija en el Select??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo con laravel deberías de enviar una petición por medio de ajax cada vez que cambies el `option` del `select`, Pero seria algo muy innecesario para una simple tarea como esa. Asi que te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

1. Agrega un `data-costo` a tu option.
2. utiliza al `javascript` o `jQuery` para hacerlo.
3. El evento `onchange` de javascript te servira o `change` de jQuery.

Dicho todo esto te paso un ejemplo de como quedaría:

```js
$("#id_tratamiento").change(function(){
  var costo=$("#id_tratamiento option:selected").data('costo');
  $("#costo").val(costo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Tratamiento</label>
<select id="id_tratamiento">
  <option selected disabled>Seleccione un tratamiento</option>
  <option value="1" data-costo="10">tratamiento 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-costo="20">tratamiento 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-costo="30">tratamiento 3</option>
  <option value="5" data-costo="50">tratamiento 5</option>
</select>

<label>Costo</label>
<input type="text" id="costo" value="" placeholder="seleccione un tratamiento">
```

Todo hecho con jQuery, en laravel tu  select quedaria asi:

```
<select class="form-control" id="id_tratamiento">
  <option selected disabled>Seleccione un tratamiento</option>
    @foreach ($servicios as $servicio)
        <option value="{{$servicio->id}}" data-costo="{{$servicio->costo}}">{{$servicio->servicio}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Tu input:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">S/</span>
    <input type="number" value="" placeholder="seleccione un tratamiento" class="form-control" id="costo">
</div>
```

Comment: Ya salio :D, te agradezco mucho por el ejemplo, tu tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: En buena hora, puedes aceptar la pregunta para que otros que se encuentren con el mismo problema puedan guiarse de ella.